# fancy captcha draggable object disappears when being dragged to circle

Tags: jquery

On my company website I've incorporated WebDesign Beach's Fancy Captcha. The CONTACT US form works. Test... at: [www.webparity.net](http://www.webparity.net/%22WebParity.net%22)

Select the ICON that's indicated and DRAG to the circle. PERFECT.... As a matter of fact, if you click the SUBMIT button first, the captcha is "captured" as not being completed.  Then move the icon and then click submit again and wala!!! It's captured...

Now, I got fancy, with fancy captcha and added a second captcha on the "websites for $999.00 and up". Bottom SUB BAR second from left.

Click on it and select any package.  This one is BLUE to indicate the difference.

So when you select a CAPTCHA icon "this time" and drag to the circle, the SECOND you click on the icon and begin moving it, it disappears. What's happening and you may debug the code in Google, is that the event handle is picking up the icon and repositioning it in an instant at top:644.54454px x left:234.34px.  This only occurs on the Website for 999.00 and up form. WHY???? Ok, I'm pretty proud of myself, but the damn things' got me going nuts...

the files in question are: jquery.captcha.two.js and captcha.css.

Comment: This captcha is woefully insecure. You're sending an Ajax request to the server to get a 'magic number'. If you complete the captcha correctly, the same 'magic number' is sent back to the server. It's security by obscurity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate ids.  I don't know if that is a bug with Fancy Captcha or your implementation.  But, all the ids in the 2nd captcha are identical to the 1st.  Only the container (ajaxFCContainer vs ajaxFCContainer1) is different.

Comment: Barbara, please review now. What's happening is that I can drag the required ICON but, the element has no idea there's a child of it being dragged.  When I drop it on the "CIRCLE" nothing happens. I'm so close... Now here's the funny part... when I use this line of code in the jquery.captcha.two.js file, line 173 - the icon is visible and drags... but when I comment out line 173 and use line 176, the icon disppears and shoots up to the upper left corner of the browser, disappearing but it does register the draggable feature in debug mode.  Your thoughts? Thanks, lastCoder, I know....

Answer (score 0):

I found it...YAY!!!!!!!!!!

Barbara, thanks for your assistance....

On LINE 173 I had to do this...

**//The line below works.... but

$(".ajax-fc-" + randVal).draggable({ containment: "#ajaxFCContainer1"});**

and on line 195 I had to do this...
**//The Drop Zone (CIRCLE)

$("#ajaxFCContainer1 #ajax-fc-content1 #ajax-fc-circle1").droppable({ //... the rest of the code**

Check it out... **[WebParity.net](http://www.webparity.net)**

Thank you everyone and LastCoder, you're right, but it seems to work and I'm not really concerned about the number thingy...